# How to print a Numpy array without brackets?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, numpy-ndarray

I want to convert `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` into `a_string = "1 2 3 4 5"`. The real numpy array is quite big (50000x200) so I assume using `for loops` is too slow.

Comment: :Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365520/numpy-converting-array-from-float-to-strings

Comment: Are you sure you really need a string representation for that big array? What for?

Comment: Afterwards I need to write this and three other arrays to a file. All the arrays have different sizes and I have to write them alternating into the file, so I am planing to do it manually using `writeline`.

Comment: The real question is why on earth doesn't np.array2string have an option to suppress the brackets.

Comment: Good question. Do you only want an answer for 1D arrays (per your example), 2D arrays (the most common), 3D or n-D arrays...?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the `join` method from string:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> ' '.join(map(str, a))
"1 2 3 4 5"
```

Comment: thanks, I tried `join` unsuccessfully before. `Map` is the missing piece for me.

Comment: a simpler variant (IMHO) would be with an iterator: `' '.join(str(n) for n in a)`

Comment: Something like this looks good:

def float2str(f):
    return '{:.5f}'.format(f)
' '.join(map(float2str, embeddings_fb.embed_token('.')))

Comment: @tito Is there any fast alternative to do the same thing. It is very slow for a big array.

Comment: @shaifaliGupta Printing is more bounded by I/O than CPU so I doubt alternative methods are going to be much faster.

Answer (score 29):

**`np.savetxt`**

Python 3 ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542683/typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-bytes-while-saving-npy-file)):

```
import numpy as np
import sys

a = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
np.savetxt(sys.stdout.buffer, a)
```

Python 2:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

a = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, a)
```

Output:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00
```

**Control the precision**

Use `fmt`:

```
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, a, fmt="%.3f")
```

output:

```
0.000
1.000
2.000
3.000
```

or:

```
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, a, fmt="%i")
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

**Get a string instead of printing**

Python 3:

```
import io
bio = io.BytesIO()
np.savetxt(bio, a)
mystr = bio.getvalue().decode('latin1')
print(mystr, end='')
```

We use `latin1` because [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) tell us that it is the default encoding used.

Python 2:

```
import StringIO
sio = StringIO.StringIO()
np.savetxt(sio, a)
mystr = sio.getvalue()
print mystr
```

**All in one line**

Or if you really want all in one line:

```
a = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, a, newline=' ')
print()
```

Output:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
```

TODO: there is a trailing space. The only solution I see is to save to a string and strip.

Tested on Python 2.7.15rc1 and Python 3.6.6, numpy 1.13.3

Answer (score 16):

Maybe a bit hacky, but I just slice them off after using `np.array2string` so:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,10)
a_str = np.array2string(a, precision=2, separator=', ')
print(a_str[1:-1])
```

Result:

```
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

`np.array2string` has lots of options also, so you can set your column width which can be very helpful with lots of data:

```
a = np.arange(0,15)
a_str = np.array2string(a, precision=2, separator=', ', max_line_width=15)
print(' ' + a_str[1:-1])
```

Gives:

```
       0,  1,  2,
       3,  4,  5,
       6,  7,  8,
       9, 10, 11,
      12, 13, 14
```

And it will smartly split at the array elements.  Note the space appended to the beginning of the string to account for aligning the first row after removing the initial bracket.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a **numpy array to begin with rather than a list** (since you mention a "real numpy array" in your post) you could use `re.sub` on the string representation of the array:

```
print(re.sub('[\[\]]', '', np.array_str(a)))
```

Again, this is assuming your array `a` was a numpy array at some point. This has the advantage of working on matrices as well.

Answer (score 4):

Numpy provides two functions for this [array_str](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html#numpy.array_str) and [array_repr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_repr.html#numpy.array_repr) -- either of which should fit your needs. Since you could use either, here's an example of each:

```
>>> from numpy import arange, reshape, array_str
>>> M = arange(10).reshape(2,5)
>>> M
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> array_str(M)
'[[0 1 2 3 4]\n [5 6 7 8 9]]'
>>> array_repr(M)
'array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],\n       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])'
```

These two functions are both highly optimized and, as such, should be preferred over a function you might write yourself. When dealing with arrays this size, I'd imagine you'd want all the speed you can get.

Comment: Using build-in functions is definitely of advantage, but it still leaves the brackets in. So this method superior for other, but similar, cases. +1

Comment: You said you need save the string to a file. If you have plans on later retrieving the string from that file it could be useful to have the brackets. Also, a combination of sub-strings and splits() would remove the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with floating-point numbers and two dimensional arrays you can also do the following:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(77)

def my_print(x):
    for row in x:
        print(' '.join(map(lambda x: "{:.3f}\t".format(x), row)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.random(size=(3, 9))
    my_print(x)
```

which prints:

```
0.919    0.642   0.754   0.139   0.087   0.788   0.326   0.541   0.240  
0.545    0.401   0.715   0.837   0.588   0.296   0.281   0.706   0.423  
0.057    0.747   0.452   0.176   0.049   0.292   0.067   0.751   0.064
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> print(*a)
1 2 3 4 5

>>> print(str(a)[1:-1])
1 2 3 4 5
```

same with lists

Comment: The str() will not work when the length of the array is long. np.array2string is an alternative.