# How to print Numpy arrays without any extra notation (square brackets [ ] and spaces between elements)?

Tags: python, arrays, formatting, numpy

I have a 2-dimensional numpy array that looks like this:

```
[[a b c]
 [d e f]
 [g h i]]
```

I'd like to print it without any of the default notational fluff that typically comes with arrays; namely the `[`, `]` and the spaces between the elements. Something like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Is it possible to do such a thing (without a trivial and possibly expensive Python loop, of course)?

I have looked at [numpy.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) but it looks like it only sets presentational options for how elements are displayed, not the characters in between.

**Edit**: The elements in the array have a string representation that can be anything, including `[`, `]` and whitespace. Minimal example of how to build such an array:

```
class custom(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'a'
a = numpy.empty((5, 5), custom)
a.fill(custom())
print a
```

Comment: Just to be clear: your custom repr includes a terminal `.` that you want to get rid of, but might include others that you don't?  I'm not sure I understand what you want to strip.

Comment: My bad, this was due to me editing the representation by hand. My original question used a numpy array of regular numbers, for which there is a `.` after each number used as delimiter (or as decimal separator, not sure). Later, I edited my question to reflect that the data type of the array was not necessarily numerical, and forgot to change the delimiter accordingly. Edited again.

Comment: Subset: only remove `[]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360103/how-to-print-a-numpy-array-without-brackets/42046765#42046765

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While this pretty much amounts to a loop, I think this is probably the best you're going to get. Generally the `join` string method is pretty fast.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[-1,-2,-3]])
>>> print '\n'.join(''.join(str(cell) for cell in row) for row in a)
123
246
-1-2-3
```

I think at this point you'd probably be best off implementing something and measuring how long it takes. My guess is that the slowest part of the code will be actually printing to console, not joining the strings together.

Comment: Well, I guess that means there is no "numpy way" to do it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 8):

```
np.savetxt(sys.stdout.buffer, a, fmt='%s', delimiter='')
```

Comment: Do you really need `.buffer` at `sys.stdout.buffer`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功, savetxt writes bytestring and so expects a binary file

Comment: Does exactly what the question asks and does so efficiently from within NumPy. Using just `sys.stdout` also works.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy    
>>> a = numpy.array([[ 1.0,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]])
>>> print str(a).replace(' ','').replace('.','').replace('[','').replace(']','')
123
456
789
```

Comment: +1 because it does answer the question I asked, but the real array in question uses a custom data type for which the string representation can be anything, including spaces and brackets. Edited the question to reflect this

Comment: @Etienne Perot - back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, if `a` is your array just do this:

```
print(re.sub('[ ]+', ' ', re.sub(' *[\\[\\]] *', '', np.array_str(a))))
```