# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes while saving .npy file

Tags: python, file-io, keras, deep-learning

I tried running the [code](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/f35fbc80e066a49d65f1688a7e99f069) in a [keras blog post.](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

The code writes to a .npy file as follows:

```
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'w'),bottleneck_features_train)
```

It then reads from this file:

```
def train_top_model():
    train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy'))
```

Now I get an error saying:

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kerasbottleneck.py", line 103, in <module>
    save_bottlebeck_features()
  File "kerasbottleneck.py", line 69, in save_bottlebeck_features
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'w'),bottleneck_features_train)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 511, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 565, in write_array
version)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 335, in _write_array_header
fp.write(header_prefix)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

After this, I tried changing the file mode from 'w' to 'wb'. This resulted in an error while reading the file:

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 800 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kerasbottleneck.py", line 104, in <module>
    train_top_model()
  File "kerasbottleneck.py", line 82, in train_top_model
    train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy'))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 404, in load
magic = fid.read(N)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: In the second code snippet brackets are not closed

Comment: Sorry, just forgot to copy that. I've edited the question now.

Comment: It is still not correct I have edited it now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code in the blog post is aimed at Python 2, where writing to and reading from a file works with bytestrings. In Python 3, you need to open the file in binary mode, both for writing and then reading again:

```
np.save(
    open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'),
    bottleneck_features_train)
```

And when reading:

```
train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))
```

Note the `b` character in the mode arguments there.

I'd use the file as a context manager to ensure it is cleanly closed:

```
with open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb') as features_train_file
    np.save(features_train_file, bottleneck_features_train)
```

and

```
with open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb') as features_train_file:
    train_data = np.load(features_train_file)
```

The code in the blog post should use *both of these changes* anyway, because in Python 2, without the `b` flag in the mode text files have platform-specific newline conventions translated, and on Windows certain characters in the stream will have specific meaning (including causing the file to appear shorter than it really is if a EOF characte appears). With binary data that could be a real problem.