# Numpy arrays without brackets

Tags: python

I want to print my array without brackets and without changing the order/format, so for example:

[image: Array with brackets]

I just want to remove the brackets from print(a). 
How can I do that?

This question is not a duplicate of others questions on that site since those solutions dont keep the format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a Numpy array without brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360103/how-to-print-a-numpy-array-without-brackets)

Comment: Do not post images of code – *even* if it's such trivial code as you show here. It is more trouble to type it in than to select and copy. Therefore, you are making it harder to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the print output, remove the brackets, then print it out again

```
import numpy as np
import io
x=np.array([[7,8,5],[3,5,7]],np.int32)
b = io.StringIO()
print(x, file=b)
s = b.getvalue()
s = s.replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ')
print(s)
```