# Python2: Convert a set of floats to a string

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, tostring, floating-point-conversion

### Question

The goal is to find a simple way for converting a set of data to a string.

Maybe I am too newby but I found nothing about conversion from a set to string. A similar question ([Numpy converting array from float to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5365520/2062965)) did not help me a lot.

### Example

The code I wrote seems definitely not ideal:

```
DataSet = {(1,4): 272.3,
           (2,4): 274.74}
print(', '.join(np.array(DataSet).astype('str'))))
```

#### Personal goal

In the end I want to create a string like:

```
DataSet = {(1,4): 272.3,
           (2,4): 274.74}
version = 2.7
print(''.join(np.array(['The data in {',
                        ', '.join(np.array(DataSet).astype('str'))),
                        '} is calculated with python%3.1f.' % version]))
```

The output should look like (it would be nice but not necessary to implement some fixed float precision):

```
'The data in {272.3, 274.7} is calculated with python2.7.'
```

Comment: `', '.join(str(i) for i in DataSet.items())`? how about `str(dataSet)`? Do you actually need to convert the individual elements, or do you only need a single string output (and if the latter, what's the desired output format for the dict?)?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your problem. Can you give a sample input/output?

Comment: @HenryKeiter: The first of your statements returns: `'((2, 4), 274.74), ((1, 4), 272.3)'`, and the second one: `'{(2, 4): 274.74, (1, 4): 272.3}'`. I did not expect the index to be printed too - but it makes sense in most cases! Do we call the structure of `DataSet` set or dictionary? @late_riser: I hope having clarified the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DataSet* is a Python dictionary and thus `DataSet.values()` returns the list of its values.
The string you need can be generated by `', '.join(map(str, DataSet.values()))` or `', '.join(str(v) for v in DataSet.values())`.