# How to change array of (rounded) floats to array of strings python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, save

I have some arrays of numbers that are rounded to 2 digits, xx.xx (decimals=2, using np.around), that I would like to save to a text document for human reading. I would like to change these 'number' arrays to arrays of strings, so that I can combine them with other arrays of strings (row and column headers) and use numpy.savetxt in order to save my data in a readable way to a text document. How can I change my arrays of 'numbers' to arrays of strings? (I believe the numbers are rounded floats, which should still be float, not sure how to check though)

```
A=np.array([57/13, 7/5, 6/8])
```

which yields array([4.384615384615385, 1.4, 0.75 ])

```
B=A.astype('|S4' )
```

yields array([b'4.38',b'1.4', b'0.75]). The b's remain when I save to txt.

```
np.savetxt('my_file.txt', B, fmt="%s)
```

How do I get rid of the b's?

I know that they talk about the b's here [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal), but I don't see how to get rid of it.

Using .astype is not a requirement, just seemed like a good way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numpy converting array from float to strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365520/numpy-converting-array-from-float-to-strings)

Comment: @Mark you can check `np.char.array()`

Comment: Is using  astype a requirement for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, it's best to use `np.savetxt(fname, data, fmt='%0.2f')`, where `data` is your original floating point array.

The `fmt` specifier is a [sprintf-style format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).  `%0.2f` specifies numbers will be displayed as floats (`f` -- as opposed to scientific notation) and formatted with as many characters as necessary to the left of the decimal point (the `0`) and 2 characters to the right of the decimal point.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([57./13, 7./5, 6./8])
np.savetxt('out.txt', a, fmt='%0.2f')
```

And the resulting `out.txt` file will look like:

```
4.38
1.40
0.75
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful; however my output looks like 4.381.400.75 (all in one line with no spaces).

Comment: @Mark - That's because it's a 1D array.  If you'd like it to be a 2D column vector, save `np.column_stack([your_data])` or `your_data[:,None]`.