# How to change array of floats to array of strings, then save to txt

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I know this question is addressed here: [Numpy converting array from float to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365520/numpy-converting-array-from-float-to-strings), but I am having trouble with the implementation.

```
A=np.array([57/13, 7/5, 6/8])
B=A.astype('|S4' )
```

yields array([b'4.38',b'1.4', b'0.75]). The b's remain when I save to txt.

```
np.savetxt('my_file.txt', B, fmt="%s")
```

The issue of why the b's are there is discussed here: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal), but with no explanation for how to get rid of them. Any help?

Also, is there any way to get rid of the ' ' around each string when printing?

Comment: `savetxt` `fmt` gives you more formatting control than `astype`.  Try `np.savetxt('myfile.txt',A,fmt='%.2f')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) -

> **'S', 'a'**     -     (byte-)string
>
> **'U'**        -        Unicode

`S` is for Byte-String, hence the `b` infront.

You should use `U` instead for unicode strings, and then save it to text.

Example -

```
A=np.array([57/13, 7/5, 6/8])
B=A.astype('U4')

np.savetxt('my_file.txt', B, fmt="%s")
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the best.